# fadeOut, removeClass not working after addClass

Tags: jquery, json, addclass, removeclass

I have a newsletter signup form that I am jazzing up.  I have this jQuery script below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(){  

    //setup variables  
    var form = $(this),  
    formData = form.serialize(),  
    formUrl = form.attr('action'),  
    formMethod = form.attr('method'),   
    responseMsg = $('#signup-response');  

    //show response message - waiting  
    responseMsg.hide()  
               .addClass('response-waiting')  
               .text('Please Wait...')  
               .fadeIn(200);  

    //send data to server for validation  
    $.ajax({  
        url: formUrl,  
        type: formMethod,  
        data: formData,  
        success:function(data){  

            //setup variables  
            var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),   
                klass = '';  

            //response conditional  
            switch(responseData.status){  
                case 'error':  
                    klass = 'response-error';  
                break;  
                case 'success':  
                    klass = 'response-success';  
                break;    
            }  

            //show reponse message  
            responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){  
                $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')  
                       .addClass(klass)  
                       .text(responseData.message)  
                       .fadeIn(200,function(){  
                           //set timeout to hide response message  
                           setTimeout(function(){  
                               responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){  
                                   $(this).removeClass(klass);  
                               });  
                           },3000);  
                        });  
             });  
          }  
    });  

    //prevent form from submitting  
    return false;  
});  
});
```

and in case you are interested, here is a snippet of my PHP (with the DB credentials removed):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == "signup"){  
mysql_connect(***REMOVEDforprivacy*******);  
mysql_select_db(***REMOVEDforprivacy*******);  

//sanitize data  
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signup-email']);  

$to ='***REMOVEDforprivacy*******';
$subject = '***REMOVEDforprivacy*******';
$body = "The email address ". $email. " has been added to the email database.";
$headers = 'From: ***REMOVEDforprivacy*******' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To:  ***REMOVEDforprivacy*******' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer:  PHP/' . phpversion();

//validate email address - check if input was empty  
if(empty($email)){  
    $status = "error";  
    $message = "You did not enter an email address!";  
}  
else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address  
    $status = "error";  
    $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";  
}  
else {  
   $existingSignup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signups WHERE email_address='$email'");  
   if(mysql_num_rows($existingSignup) < 1){  



       $insertSignup = mysql_query("INSERT INTO signups (email_address) VALUES ('$email')");  
       if($insertSignup){  
           $status = "success";  
           $message = "You have been signed up!";
            mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
       }  
       else {  
           $status = "error";  
           $message = "Oops, There has been a technical error!";  
       }  
    }  
    else {  
        $status = "error";  
        $message = "Looks like you have already registered this email address with us.  Thank you for your support!";  
    }  
}  

//return json response  
$data = array(  
    'status' => $status,  
    'message' => $message  
);  

echo json_encode($data);  

exit;  
}  


?>
```

Everything works smoothly up to here:

```
//show reponse message  
            responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){  
                $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')  
                       .addClass(klass)  
                       .text(responseData.message)  
                       .fadeIn(200,function(){  
                           //set timeout to hide response message  
                           setTimeout(function(){  
                               responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){  
                                   $(this).removeClass(klass);  
                               });  
                           },3000);  
                        });  
             });
```

I do not get what is wrong here.  Syntax *seems* to be fine, however, when I tried removing most of it and just using `responseMsg.fadeOut(200);` the responseMsg does not fade (so you can forget it removing the class and adding in the new one).  I have inspected this with Firebug, and the POST response does show the correct error and success messages are being returned...(and indeed checking my db, entries get added and an alert email gets sent out)......so all is working except the fancy schnazzy JQuery effects.  I briefly thought I had a JQuery conflict from another element on the page, so I removed that, and there is no change.  I tried using $.noconflict(), $.noconflict(true), and replacing all instances of $ with JQuery (but then, the other item on the page wasn't conflicting anyways).  I tried removing the call to add the 'response-waiting' class and just add in the response message classes after the JSON parse of the data, but THAT didn't work.  I pretty much copied and pasted this script from [this awesome tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-sleek-ajax-signup-form/comment-page-1/#comments), so I am at a loss as to why it doesn't work.  Anyone got a clue?

**UPDATE**

FWIW here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8nhR/1/), although it absolutely doesn't work without the PHP DB stuff....not sure how I could work around that, guys....

**UPDATE**  Got it working, stupid mistake on placing my PHP code NOT above my html header...will post as answer as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: It would be nice to have a jsfiddle example detailing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I meant you should trim down the code to replicate your problem. Generally, you will ferret out your problem. This works fine (simulating the form submission by just firing the event on click):

http://jsfiddle.net/k8nhR/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#signup-button').click(function(){  

        responseMsg = $("#signup-response");
                 //show response message - waiting  
         responseMsg.hide()  
                    .addClass('response-waiting')  
                    .text('Please Wait...')  
                    .fadeIn(200);  

        var responseData =  { status : "success", message: "success message"};
                var klass = '';

                //response conditional  
                switch(responseData.status){  
                    case 'error':  
                        klass = 'response-error';  
                    break;  
                    case 'success':  
                        klass = 'response-success';  
                    break;  
                }  

                //show reponse message  
                responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){  
                   $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')  
                          .addClass(klass)  
                          .text(responseData.message)  
                          .fadeIn(200,function(){  
                              //set timeout to hide response message  
                              setTimeout(function(){  
                                  responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){  
                                      $(this).removeClass(klass);  

                                  });  
                               },3000)  
                           });  
                });   
      });  
    });
```

​

Comment: If I remove any kind of DB form submission stuff, this helps my JSFiddle; unfortunately I am lost as to how I can make this work when there is a form involved.

Comment: Ok, I got it working.....my PHP code was inside my html, and not above everything!  :/  thank you for your advice about breaking things down in JSFiddle!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the Klass variable before the success function so it's retrievable by the call back function, and instead of using a setTimeout, just use a .delay()